# How to declare a flowtype library definition for polymorphic functions

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

What is the proper way to specify the type definitions a polymorphic method that depending on the parameter types has different return types?

index.js:

```
// @flow
import {func1} from './lib1';
const s: string = func1('string');
const b: boolean = func1(); // should cause type error but does not!
```

lib1.js:

```
export function func1(p) {
    return (typeof p === 'string') ? p : 0;
}
```

defs/lib1.js.flow

```
// @flow
declare module "lib1" {
    declare export function func1(p: string): string;
    declare export function func1(_: void): number;
}
```

.flowconfig:

```
[libs]
defs/
```

I would have hoped to received an error message in index.js(4) but flow does not complain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the example you gave is how to declare an overloaded function. However, you may want to change the second line to:

```
declare function myFunc(_: void): number;
```

Since Flow allows a function to be called with too many arguments (though [not for much longer](https://flow.org/blog/2017/05/07/Strict-Function-Call-Arity/)), it may select the second overload even if the function is called with a string. The modification I suggest makes it so the argument must be `undefined` (which is what is implicitly passed if you just leave off an argument).

Comment: Thank you for your help Nat! Unfortunately it does not work as expected. I have modified my question with a complete example and would have expected to get an error in indfex.js(4) but flow does not complain.

Comment: You are conflating library definitions with implementation files. You are importing from `./lib1`, which looks at the implementation file. It looks like you are not getting type checking on the use of that function because `lib1.js` does not have `@flow` at the top. If you imported from `lib1` Flow would look at the library definition file (but then of course it would not be found at runtime).

Comment: I probably made a mistake in my example but right now, I'm confused. lib1.js would be an example for an un-typed external library and defs/lib1.js.flow would be the library definition file that adds the type information missing in lib1.js. It is my understanding that I have to add the library definition file exactly because I have no access to the library.

Comment: Just remove `lib1.js` and change the import `lib1` (not a relative import). This will simulate the situation you are asking about.